# How To Redirect to a Named Node upon Registration

Tags: 6, users, redirection

Given a D6 site where users must confirm their email address, I would like new registrants to be immediately redirected to a Page node which explains the email verification process.

I attempted to do this using Actions and Triggers, but "Trigger: After a user account has been created" executes before the activation email is sent and so the message is blocked and never gets out. This appears to be an unresolved issue tracing as far back as D5.

The [Login Destination](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination) module is listed as supporting this feature for D7.x but not 6.x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Rules Module](http://drupal.org/project/rules) to redirect a user after an account is created.

- Simply add a new rule for the event "User account has been created"
- Add an action of "Page redirect"
- Fill in the information for the page you want to redirect the user to.

Make sure that "Immediately issue the page redirect" is **not** checked or else the same thing will happen and the email will not get sent.

Comment: Thanks! The Rules module is great and I foresee using it a lot int he future.

Answer (score 0):

Another good solution would be to use [LoginToboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan)